# Why do many examples for requestAnimationFrame invoke requestAnimationFrame outside the callback?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

Many examples I see online of RequestAnimationFrame call the function twice: inside and outside the callback.  I understand why we call it inside; however, any reason why we call it outside?

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#Notes)

```
let myReq;

function step(timestamp) {
  myReq = requestAnimationFrame(step); // I understand why we call it here.
  console.log(timestamp, myReq)
  if(timestamp >= 1000) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(myReq);
  }
}

myReq = requestAnimationFrame(step);  // why invoke rAF here.
```

Comment: The call outside is starting the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the initial call to `step`, at the next animation frame; it is essentially kicking off the animation.  Without it, you have this:

```
let myReq;

function step(timestamp) {
  myReq = requestAnimationFrame(step);
  console.log(timestamp, myReq)
  if(timestamp >= 1000) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(myReq);
  }
}
```

...in which case, we never have a caller to `step` and it is never invoked.

Alternately you could omit the `requestAnimationFrame` wrapper to the initial invocation of `step`:

```
let myReq;

function step(timestamp) {
  myReq = requestAnimationFrame(step); // I understand why we call it here.
  console.log(timestamp, myReq)
  if(timestamp >= 1000) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(myReq);
  }
}

myReq = step;  // why invoke rAF here.
```

But then the very first time `step` is invoked it will not necessarily wait for the first available animation frame.

Comment: Ha! it's to get on that first frame! totally makes sense!